# Resetting a key in My.Setting

Tags: .net, winforms, settings, application-settings

I know it's possible to reset the `My.Settings` with `Reset()` method.

Is there anyway to do the same thing for just one setting? Or simple getting its default value instead of the one changed by user. (*I'm referring to User Scope Settings*)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot reset one setting. It is easy to get the default value through the `Properties` collection. Specifically, the `SettingsProperty`'s `DefaultValue` property. Moreover, the `PropertyValues` collection contains `SettingsPropertyValue` objects that allow you to determine if a property/setting has changed through the `IsDirty` or `UsingDefaultValue` properties.

```
    Dim a As Object = My.Settings.Properties.Item("fred").DefaultValue
    Dim b As Boolean = My.Settings.PropertyValues.Item("fred").IsDirty
    Dim c As Boolean = My.Settings.PropertyValues.Item("fred").UsingDefaultValue
```

I wish there was a way to get these values without having to specify the name of the setting.

Comment: Please explain the down vote. This is an accepted answer. The question is answer and a work around provided. Therefore, providing a comment would help.

Comment: I can never get `UsingDefaultValue` to work. It's always false, no matter where in my code I check it. `IsDirty` seems to work ok.

Comment: Also, I've found that with `StringCollection` type settings that you can't compare the current value with the `DefaultValue` because the latter is a serialized XML string while the former is deserialized to a collection/array.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about resetting just one setting but you could copy the settings to another object, `Reset()` and then copy back all the settings values except the one you wanted to reset.